# Rust notebook in colab; how to run Google's example

Tags: rust, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

Google colab gives an example of how to run a Rust Jupyter notebook on the web [here](https://colab.research.google.com/github/vistec-AI/colab/blob/master/rust.ipynb#scrollTo=w1vDka50zZnA).  However, I get an error when trying to follow the directions:

[image]

I followed the instructions at the top of the notebook, so this is confusing.  The only thing I can think is that I'm not "reloading" properly.  I assumed that meant restarting the kernel, but that didn't seem to work.  All thoughts welcome!

Answer (score 1):

From colab [faq](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/faq.html)

> What about other programming languages?
>
> Colab focuses on supporting Python and its ecosystem of third-party
> tools. We're aware that users are interested in support for other
> Jupyter kernels (eg R or Scala). We would like to support these, but
> don't yet have any ETA.

Colab doesnot support rust kernel for now.